# Krakend generate command not found

Tags: krakend

I am using krakend version `1.4.0` docs say I can run generate commands to get OpenAPI, postman or config to graph.

when I try to run any of these commands. I get
`Error: unknown command "generate" for "krakend"`

do I need to do something differently to enable `generate` commands? Heres a link for generator commands. https://www.krakend.io/docs/enterprise/commands/openapi/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a KrakenD Enterprise documentation link, but you are using the community Edition. There is no command generate on the free version as per 1.4.